# How to get Android (emulator) to load a native dependency that ships with a C# (Avalonia) app?

Tags: c#, android, avaloniaui

Given a new C# Avalonia solution in Visual Studio, with a PackageReference that brings in a native dependency, how can the Android app be made to find and load that native dependency?
The referenced nuget package utilizes the `runtimes\android-x64\native` folder for its native `lib*.so` library, and msbuild seems to recognize it and copy it into the .apk folder that presumably gets distributed to the Android emulator. So why then do I get a runtime exception saying the library cannot be found?

Minimal repro with issue describing the problem here: 
https://github.com/AArnott/Avalonia-WithNativeDependency/issues/1